# Edittext input validation in android

Tags: android

I have a scenario in which I have a form with four fields. In which one field will take same input only 5 times. On entering in 6th times activity will not go to another activity on button click. Please somebody help me as I have spent so many hours.

Here is my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText phone, emailId, doctorName, doctorUniqueNumber;
    private Button submitButton;

    private String code;

    public LoginFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        phone = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        emailId = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.emailId);
        doctorName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.doctorName);
        doctorUniqueNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.doctorUniqueNumber);
        submitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(click);

        return rootView;
    }

    View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ((!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()) && (!doctorName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    && (!emailId.getText().toString().isEmpty()) && (!doctorUniqueNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())){
                AuthenticateDoctor doctor = new AuthenticateDoctor();
                doctor.execute();
            }

        }
    };

    private void setPrefs(String key, int value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private int getPrefs(String key, int defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    private void setStringPrefs(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    private String getStringPrefs(String key, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    private class AuthenticateDoctor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

        private final String LOG_TAG = AuthenticateDoctor.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String data;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("http://spirantcommunication.com/andriod/grl/show.php?" + "code=" +
                        doctorUniqueNumber.getText().toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }

                data = buffer.toString();
                Log.v("Data", data);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("Message");
                code = array.getString(0);
                Log.v("Code", code);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (code.equals("success")){
                int numberOfTimes = getPrefs("Number of Times", 0);
                if (numberOfTimes > 5){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Exceed value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setStringPrefs("Doctor Unique Number", " ");
                }else {
                    numberOfTimes++;
                    setPrefs("Number of Times", numberOfTimes);
                    setStringPrefs("Doctor Unique Number", doctorUniqueNumber.getText().toString());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DoctorDashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }else if (code.equals("Faliure")){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This unique number is not present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is error? try to see if numberOfTimes in SHaredPreference changes correctly

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have an int member in LoginFragment which will store the attempts. Then, in onClick you will check: if(attempts > 5) return; attempts++;

```
View.OnClickListener click = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if(attempts > 5) return;

             attempts++;

            if ((!phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()) && (!doctorName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    && (!emailId.getText().toString().isEmpty()) && (!doctorUniqueNumber.getText().toString().isEmpty())){
                attempts = 0;
                AuthenticateDoctor doctor = new AuthenticateDoctor();
                doctor.execute();
            }

        }
    };
```

Hope it helps